# Session timeout settings in IBM Websphere

Tags: websphere, session-timeout

Is it possible to take user to customized webpage after session timeout? What is the parameter to be set in websphere for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of such settings in WAS.

I think your best chance will be to implement a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that will check the session validity and will redirect or continue with the chain if it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the redirection from your code.

For example, in a servlet when `request.getSession(false)` returns null, redirect the request to a Login page.